# How to return a button to its default color after being pressed?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-button

I have created a few buttons in my android application. When they are pressed the color changes to green and purple. I have also created a reset button that when pressed will return the pressed buttons to their original or default color.

How do I get the default color to appear?

Comment: You can save the default background as Drawable before you change it.

Comment: a proper way to handle it is defining separate states for your button. take a look at [this](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.com/2012/11/android-custom-states-for-state-list.html)

Comment: How do you save the default background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first get the default background of Button b; using

```
Drawable d = b.getBackground();
```

then set another background of your choice

```
b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_button1);
```

if you need default background again use this

```
b.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

manage your code using these lines.

it will helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Android provides state list drawables which can be defined via xml files. You can define various states like default, pressed, focused, etc in your state list drawable xml file and then apply that xml to the view as a background resource.

You can read about them [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html).